# What is the best way to scrape a drop down menu with Puppeteer without scraping sub-menus?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, screen-scraping

I have been having trouble when trying to scrape a simple website, I am new to this thus there might be some mistakes, I retrieve the data from a drop down menu with categories, and it works but I am not sure as to how I can avoid scraping sub-menus since the collected text is a complete mess. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    
    (async()=>{
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true});
        try{
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width:1920, height: 1080})
        await page.goto('https://www.tiendasjumbo.co/');
        await page.waitForSelector('#home-page > nav > div:nth-child(1) > button.button-categories.toggleSlide');
    
            const element = await page.$("#home-page > div.navigation__toggle.wrapper.page-menu > div.center > div.navigation_categories > ul");
            const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
            console.log(text);
    
        }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
        }finally{
            await browser.close();
        }
    
    
    })();
```

Comment: You can try `.innerText` instead of `.textContent` for the readable part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.trim()`, to delete al spaces and `.innerText` to prepare your strings.

`const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.innerText.trim(), element);`